# startActivity() is not working on Android without exception

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In the following code, I can not start the AsyncListImage activity from the TakePicture activity.

There is no exception during executing. The program just went into Looper.loop() as seen from the debugger.

```
public class TakePicture extends Activity {

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ImgTaker.PHOTO_PICKED_WITH_DATA: {
            // DO Something with searchResult
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, AsyncListImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("result", searchResult);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case ImgTaker.CAMERA_WITH_DATA: {
            mCurrentPhotoFile = new File(ImgTaker.getPhotoPath());
            ImgTaker.doCropPhoto(this, mCurrentPhotoFile);
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

I do have a declaration of AsyncListImage activity in manifest.xml.

```
    <activity android:name=".AsyncListImage"></activity>
```

Comment: Do you see anything in Logcat? Is TakePicture in a TabHost or ViewGroup?

Comment: Are you that sure the startActivity() is reached? Add logging after a invocation. Good style is add to a default block of switch operator 'throw new IllegalArgumentException()'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out the problem is that the `searchResult` is too large for `binder` IPC causing `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION`. By limiting the size of `searchResult`, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest,try to give the complete path to access the class like "com.stack.example.AsyncListImage"